# Setting up TideSDK in Titanium Studio

Tags: sdk, osx-lion, titanium, tidesdk

i am trying to setup the tidesdk in titanium studio but it won't work for some reason... Here is what i've done so far:

- Downloaded Titanium Studio v2.1.2.201208301612 from appcelerator
- Downloaded TideSDK v1.2.0.RC4 from tidesdk.org
- Added the sdk in Titanium Studio like this: "Help > install specific
  titanium sdk"

Basically i just followed the instructions from this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/titanium-desktop-transition/wv6fiRD6Sbo
But the option to start a new desktop project won't come up. Is there something i am doing wrong or something?

I am using lion 10.7.4, according to this google group that shouldn't be a problem. Anyone's got any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Here are a couple of things to help you on your way:

Lion and Mountain Lion with Xcode 4.x are supported in the upcoming 1.3.0 but not 1.2.0.RC4. 1.2.0.RC4 will work fine with Snow Leopard 10.6.x on Xcode 3.x. Another possibility in the short term is to consider developing on either a Windows 7, or Ubuntu 11.04 virtual machine until the 1.3.0-beta has released. This release is expected very soon and provides updates to core libraries and offers support for current operating system versions of OSX, Windows and Linux.

Code you write in 1.2.0.RC4 will work fine in 1.3.0 since there are no API changes. The only change will be in the JavaScript namespace. In 1.3.0, the JavaScript namespace for the future will use 'Ti' as opposed to 'Titanium'. By setting a global variable in your code, you can start using 'Ti' to begin with.

`var Ti = Titanium;`

As far as Titanium Studio, unfortunately Appcelerator dropped the desktop support but have revived it. They have come out with an update that is reported to work:

http://preview.appcelerator.com/appcelerator/studio/desktop/update/beta/

If your run into any issue, an alternative is to download TiDev Community:

http://api.appcelerator.net/p/pages/app_page?token=m4rZLSv6

TiDev Community is really reaching the end of its life cycle but it will work for creating in running your apps in the short term.

The TideSDK team has a new app under development called TideSDK Builder. TideSDK Builder will provide the basics of creating, running and packaging your apps. It will also feature scaffolds for kickstarting your app projects. A new tidebuilder CLI will also be available with comparable functionality. We are hoping to bundle these for the official release of 1.3.0 that is targeted for the end of September.

Appcelerator has provided a Titanium Studio SDK. The TideSDK team is exploring this to see that Titanium Studio IDE can continue for the future.

One last thing to keep in mind is that Titanium Studio and TiDev Community no longer support the network packaging service that Appcelerator once offered. This means local packaging in the interim while TideSDK team continues to examine options.

Please follow TideSDK on twitter for updates and announcements at http://twitter.com/TideSDK