# tidesdk install titanium studio error

Tags: xcode, macos, titanium, tidesdk

I follow instructions from [Setting up TideSDK in Titanium Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504503/setting-up-tidesdk-in-titanium-studio) with my actual configuration :

- Mac OS X 10.8.3 and Xcode 4.6.1
- Titanium Studio build 3.0.2.201302191606
- TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-osx-x86-64

But when I try to install TideSDK downloaded zip via Help/Install Titanium SDK..., I get this error :

```
File not found: /var/folders/ts/1gfpg44s2ks3lqhd3rt79dh40000gn/T/TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-osx-x86-64.zip310468998/modules/osx/php/1.3.1-beta/libticrypto.0.dylib.
```

This file exists however...
How can I still use Titanium Studio as an IDE with TideSDK for Desktop apps (get around this error ou by an other way) ?

Thanks a lot !

Adrien C.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Titanium Studio supports TideSDK anymore. Try downloading TideSDK Developer from the website http://tidesdk.org.